# Laravel Queues with AWS SQS. How do I run just one job per queue?

Tags: laravel, queue, amazon-sqs

I'm new to Laravel Queues and just built a test code like this:

```
class TestController extends Controller {

public function testQueue2()
{
    Queue::push('QueueController@fire', array('id' => 114));
}
```

and the queue task is:

```
class QueueController extends Controller {

public function fire($job, $data)
{
    Log::info('This is some useful information.'.$data['id']);
}
```

Than I hit the URL to run the Queue test. SQS worked well and my server log get these info:

[2015-06-07 15:53:04] production.INFO: This is some useful information.114 [] []

[2015-06-07 15:53:36] production.INFO: This is some useful information.114 [] []

[2015-06-07 15:53:37] production.INFO: This is some useful information.114 [] []

[2015-06-07 15:54:09] production.INFO: This is some useful information.114 [] []

[2015-06-07 15:54:10] production.INFO: This is some useful information.114 [] []

[2015-06-07 15:54:42] production.INFO: This is some useful information.114 [] []

I want the queue task be executed only once, not 6 times, how should I do for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Laravel 4.2 for this. From the documentation:

> The first argument given to the push method is the name of the class that should be used to process the job

I think you only need to specify the method to use if you don't want to use the `fire` method of the Job class.

In other words, try modifying your code to be:

```
Queue::push('QueueController', array('id' => 114));
```

It's also kind of strange to have your Controller be the implementor of this job execution, but that's a different matter.